# How can calculate camera rotation with Lucas-Kanade tracker in openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, tracker

I want to calculate the camera rotation with Lucas-Kanade tracker in openCV with phython

I know how to see it in the camera-screen and I have to calculate it in degrees/seconds.